# Combine lead and lag function without overlap

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
COL
---
B
C
D
```

I need to get an output like this:

```
COL1          COL2
----          ----
Creation         B
       B         C
       C         D
       D   Pending
```

I've tried a normal lead

```
nvl(lead(col) order by col , 'Creation')
```

window function, but that would only show the first 'Creation' and not that last 'Pending' that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table has `N` records (`3` in the example provided) when query must return `N + 1` (`4`); let's modify the initial data in order to query `N + 1` records:

```
  with q as (
    -- Additional null record
    select null as Col
      from dual 

     union all

    -- Added to the initial table 
    select col
      from myTable
  )

  select nvl(Lag(COL) over (order by col), 'Creation') as Col1,
         nvl(Col, 'Pending') as Col2
    from q
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/230e1/27)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all`:

```
(select null, col
 from t
 order by col
 fetch first 1 row only
) union all
(select col, lead(col) over (order by col)
 from t
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use lead and lag in separate subqueries, and union those together; that would produce duplicates if unioned together with `all`:

```
select lag(col) over (order by col) as col1, col as col2
from your_table
union all -- all just to show raw values before duplicates are supressed
select col as col1, lead(col) over (order by col) as col2
from your_table
```

```
COL1 COL2
---- ----
B
B    C
C    D
B    C
C    D
D
```

But if you union without `all` those duplicates are supressed; and with that as an inline view (or CTE) you can then apply `nvl` or `coalesce` to the null values to get the fixed strings you want:

```
select coalesce(col1, 'Creation') as col1, coalesce(col2, 'Pending')
from (
  select lag(col) over (order by col) as col1, col as col2
  from your_table
  union
  select col as col1, lead(col) over (order by col) as col2
  from your_table
) t
order by t.col1 nulls first, t.col2 nulls last
```

```
COL1     COL2
-------- --------
Creation B
B        C
C        D
D        Pending
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ba16bcd14ab123e91770acbba779a68)

Hitting the table twice is potentially less performant than adding a single dummy row via `dual`; but as the original values are available to you can explicitly order the result, without introducing a flag.